# Add to Available Fonts in gVim

Tags: vim

While at work, I'm sadly forced to use Windows. I'm unhappy with (read: rageful toward) the font choices gVim offers, and I'd like to change it to the font I use on my dev computer at home.

However, gVim has limited options when it comes to what is available with the set guifont= option. Even though I know the font in question is great with VIM, as I use it elsewhere, I don't know how to add to the list of available fonts even though I have installed it on this machine, and I can't find this information anywhere.

Does anyone have any insight into this? I really don't understand why I can't set the guifont to be any monospace font I damn well please, instead of what gVim thinks is best.

Comment: As far as I know, you can use any font installed in the computer. How are you setting it? The syntax can change a bit depending on the OS.

Comment: currently I have set guifont="SV\ Basic\ Manual\ 10" - it doesn't change anything. It will only change to fonts that are actually on the list when doing set guifont=<tab>. I have also tried set guifont="SV_Basic_Manual" (underscore notation instead of escaped spaces).

Comment: I have this problem trying to get Monaco onto Windows 11 with gVim

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I've just downloaded, unpacked, installed [DejaVu Sans Mono](http://dejavu-fonts.org/wiki/Main_Page) and it's added to the list.

I've done the same with [your font](http://www.dafont.com/sv-basic-manual.font) and it's not added to the list.

It's probably a problem with the font itself.

From `:help guifont` I gather that, on Windows, Gvim only accepts monospaced fonts.

From the description your font seems to be monospaced but it's probably not 100% exact: I don't know if it's a glitch or what but the boxes on the pages don't seem to align very well.

I think that a monospaced font should make all the boxes aligned.

Comment: Wow! Hey, thanks for going through all that. At least I know I'm not missing something. I've never had problems with that font as a terminal font in the past, but you're right that maybe gVim only accepts those which are 100% exact.

Comment: No problem. I've tried lots of programming fonts but I didn't recognized the name so I had to give it a look.